# grub2 font advice doesn't work

Tags: fedora, grub, grub2, fedora-31

I'm running Fedora 31 on a Lenovo T470p, with GNU GRUB version 2.03 platform x86_64-efi .

I wish to have a far larger font.

As many, many suggestions on the internet advise:

1] I've added the `GRUB_FONT` line to my /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub2/DejaVuSans-Bold.pf2
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/swap rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
GRUB_GFX_MODE=960x540
```

2] I've done the following:

```
grub2-mkfont -s 24 -o /boot/grub2/DejaVuSans-Bold.pf2 /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
```

If I grep `/etc/grub2-efi.cfg` for the new timeout I changed at the same time (-1) I see it.

If I grep `/etc/grub2-efi.cfg` for font (case-insensitive) or part of the font name (`Dej`) I **do not**.  If all the info grub uses at startup is in `/etc/grub2-efi.cfg`, then it seems `grub2-mkconfig` is not putting it in there, and that would be the problem.

When I boot, I indeed **do** see the effect of my timeout change.  (There is no timeout.  Good.)  But I see the same old tiny font.

When I boot and use "c" to get to a prompt, and try the `lsfonts` command, I see `Loaded fonts:` followed by another prompt.  In other words, no fonts.  I don't know if that means anything.

One approach I've read on the 'net is to set `GRUB_GFX_MODE=640x480` but that change has no effect.  The GNU doc for 2.0.6 suggests using a GRUB command `videoinfo`, I assume at the GRUB prompt, but I don't seem to have that command available at the prompt reached by hitting "C" at the menu.

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#gfxmode

Looking at /etc/grub.d/00_header, it seems to be doing some check on my font file and if it doesn't like it for some reason (I don't know sh as I started programming when perl4 was just getting big) it won't output anything.  And indeed, in my /etc/grub2-efi.cfg, I see comments showing the beginning and end of processing without any mention of font.

Looking further at that file, it seems like a variable `gfxterm` is set *only* if `GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"` ... something that none of the many pages telling how to set font size mention.  I would change my `GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT` thusly, but when googling for it, I see mention that at least on some systems it's resulting in blank screens and unbootable systems.  This leads to a final subquestion: if I render the system unbootable with an edit of `/etc/default/grub` ... how do I boot it?

Comment: is that your personal home laptop?